# AttributeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QPixmap' object has no attribute 'setDevicePixelRatio'

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyside

this is a project by my colleague with dimission, some error occured when debugging:

> File "D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python2.7\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5.py",
>   line 591, in _icon
>       pm.setDevicePixelRatio(self.canvas._dpi_ratio) AttributeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QPixmap' object has no attribute 'setDevicePixelRatio'

Environment: PyCharm 2017 + Python 2.7.13
Packages:

[image]

how can i solve it?

Comment: read this: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8570

Comment: Try installing pyqt5.

Comment: i've installed python-qt5 and the problem is solved, thank u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I solved this problem by installing python-qt5, sorry for closing the question so late.